# I2C Data Line Holding Low for 10 Seconds

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, i2c, communication

I am currently working on a device that has a total of 20 I2C devices connected to it. This includes 4 ADS1115 modules, 3 MCP23017 GPIO extenders, 4 NAU7802 weight scale modules with a TCA9548A multiplexer, 1 I2C-based pump motor with an AM4096 encoder, 4 I2C-based AS5600 encoders, and several other I2C devices.

In this setup, a Jetson Nano with Ubuntu installed is functioning as the I2C master. I have implemented 6 different processes to read data from different I2C slaves. Most of the time, these processes work fine for 24 hours or more. However, occasionally, I encounter a strange issue where the data line holds low for exactly 10 seconds. During this time, the clock signal, which is controlled by the master, also stops working. Interestingly, this issue can occur with the motor pump, NAU7802, or ADS1115 modules, but the duration of the data line being held low is consistently 10 seconds regardless of the specific module involved.

I have tried using both the SMBus library and Linux's simple read/write functions, but I am encountering errors. In my case, the data line is always busy, and I cannot afford to wait for the 10-second bus lockup to be released since I need to read data from other functions as well. I have examined the bus waveforms using an oscilloscope, but they appear to be fine.

I have attached some snapshots of the logic analyzer for reference. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide insights into why this phenomenon is occurring

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 10 s sounds a lot like a default value for some software timeout. Maybe there is a problem with i2c drivers or how you use them.

Comment: How does the bus recover from this 10-sec clock low? The problem might be that you have mixed both SMBus and standard I2C devices. SBMBus devices are supposed to time out after 25ms. I do have to wonder if it would be about 6 tasks accessing a single bus somehow.

Comment: @Justme During this phenomenon, I have observed that the clock signal goes high while the data line remains low for a duration of 10 seconds. I am perplexed as to why the clock signal stops working, even though the master has continuous control over it. i have attached new pic you can see that.

Comment: There is data activity at the end of 10 sec delay. Please zoom in on that what happens on clock and data at the end of the delay. But if there is a problem on bus, the master may think that someone else has sent start and is jammed waiting for the another master to release the bus. Also the logic analyzer does not show if there are analog problems on the bus, it hides them. Perhaps provide a schematics. 20 physical chips on the bus is a lot and all the chips must be handled with the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Run dmesg on the jetson and look for weird stuff - I had a robot that would lose all can communication because the wifi module on my TX2 caused an sdio fault which triggered a bus timing retrain - whole computer would lock up for a quarter second only to come back with a “nah looks good boss” at which point my motor drivers were panicking. Best part was I wasn’t even using the hecking wifi.

Comment: @JustmeYes, you are right. I also think it's an arbitration issue. However, I have only one master and all other devices are slaves. It's possible that some devices are malfunctioning, causing the master to go into an arbitration state. Could you please tell me how to disable arbitration in Linux or how to ensure that the master is recognized as the single master?